# using array as global vs local variable

Tags: c, data-structures

I've been working on DFS algorithm in graph and got stuck in using local variables.
I have a code looking like this:

```
#define MAX_VERTICES 50

typedef struck GraphType {
    int n; // number of nodes
    int adj_mat[MAX_VERTICES][MAX_VERTICES];
} GraphType;

int visited[MAX_VERTICES];

void insert_vertex(GraphType* g, int v) {
    if (((g->n) + 1) > MAX_VERTICES) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Graph: size of vertices ERROR");
        return;
    }
    g->n++;
}

void insert_edge(GraphType* g, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= g->n || end >= g->n) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Graph: number of vertices ERROR");
        return;
    }
    g->adj_mat[start][end] = 1;
    g->adj_mat[end][start] = 1;
}
void dfs_mat(GraphType* g, int v) {
    int w;
    visited[v] = TRUE;
    printf("vertex %d -> ", v);
    for (w = 0; w < g->n; w++) {
        if (g->adj_mat[v][w] && !visited[w])
            dfs_mat(g, w);
}

int main(void) {
    GraphType *g;
    g = (GraphType*)malloc(sizeof(GraphType));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        insert_vertex(g, i);
    insert_edge(g, 0, 1);
    insert_edge(g, 0, 2);
    insert_edge(g, 0, 3);
    insert_edge(g, 1, 2);
    
    dfs_mat(g, 0);
    free(g);
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is making that **visited[MAX_VERTICES]** array into a local variable(so that I can give it as a parameter to other functions). How can I add it into main function and delete it from global usage? Maybe by using pointers?

Comment: You don't need to make it local just to pass it to a function. Just pass the address (i.e. the name, which the C compiler resolves into the address).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, while this is technically correct, it's functionally still quite different to pass it as a local or global array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will just declare the array inside the main function and pass it as an argument of type int * to every function you need it.

```
void dfs_mat(GraphType* g, int *visited, int v) {
    int w;
    visited[v] = TRUE;
    printf("vertex %d -> ", v);
    for (w = 0; w < g->n; w++) {
        if (g->adj_mat[v][w] && !visited[w])
            dfs_mat(g, w);
}
```

Comment: If the array, is passed as local parameter, then it's length should also be passed as such. Also how is it guaranteed that `w` doesn't exceed the size of the array?

Comment: Well, how to avoid the buffer overflow is another problem that mus be revisited later in the code. Passing the length of the array as argument is an option. The question was generic so i provided a simple example.